# how to do React reset for refresh component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

I would like to put a reset to refresh the status of my input.
I tested online 13 this: `this.messageForm.reset()` but the error I get and is not a function

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {Form, Button} from 'reactstrap'


export default class Formulaire extends Component {

createMessage = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log(this.message.value)
    const message = this.message.value
    this.props.addMessage(message)
    //reset
    this.messageForm.reset()
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Form 
                className='form' 
                onSubmit={event =>this.createMessage(event)}
                ref={input => this.messageForm = input}
                >
                <textarea 
                    required 
                    maxLength='140'
                    ref={input => this.message = input}
                >

                </textarea>
                <Button type="submit"> Envoyer! </Button>
            </Form>
        </div>

    )
}
}
```

Comment: Why not just set this.messageForm = undefined?

Comment: Where is `messageForm`? I can't see this, also the code for `reset`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your `<Form>` is not a HTML form element, but a [reactstrap Form component](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/form/) and as such, it doesn't have a `.reset()` method.

Reactstrap allows setting the `innerRef` prop to access the actual DOM element:

```
<Form 
  className='form' 
  onSubmit={event =>this.createMessage(event)}
  innerRef={input => this.messageForm = input}
>
```

Comment: I deleted reactstrap and added inneref to line 19. I still have an error. "TypeError: Cannot read property 'reset' of undefined.

Comment: Don't delete reactstrap if you're using `innerRef`. If you delete reactstrap then use the usual `ref`.